# node require bluebird failing

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I am running a node.js app and for some reason the node app is failing when requiring the bluebird module `require('bluebird')`.

- node version: `0.10.40`
- bluebird version: `3.3.4`

This is really strange and the only thing I have to go off of is the stack trace here:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined  
    at Object.setBounds (app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:614:48)  
    at module.exports (app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:762:11)  
    at Object.<anonymous> (app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/bluebird.js:9:36)  
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)  
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    var firstStackLines = firstLineError.stack.split("\n");
```

Again, the app runs just fine. When I add this one line `require('bluebird')` it crashes and I get this stack trace. Any ideas on what this error is coming from?

**[Edit]**

at line `node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:614:48`

```
> console.log(firstLineError);
[Error]
> console.log(firstLineError.message);

> console.log(firstLineError.stack);
undefined
> console.log(firstLineError.toString());
Error: Error
> console.log(firstLineError instanceof Error);
True
```

It is an Error object that is essentially empty

**temporary solution**

When I change the line `node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:614` to

```
var firstStackLines = (firstLineError.stack) ? firstLineError.stack.split("\n") : "";
```

and line 615 to

```
var lastStackLines = (lastLineError.stack) ? lastLineError.stack.split("\n") : "";
```

it works just fine. Not sure if this has lasting effects though

Comment: what's happening at `app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:614:48`?

Comment: `var firstStackLines = firstLineError.stack.split("\n");`

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(firstLineError)` just before that point, and see what's in there?

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar failures, more specifically:

```
.../node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:673
var firstStackLines = firstLineError.stack.split("\n");
```

when using node 6.2.2 with bluebird^3.4.1.

Upgrading to bluebird^3.4.6 with node v6.2.2 helped fix the error.

Comment: I have the same issue with node v 6.7.0 and bluebird 3.4.6
var firstStackLines = firstLineError.stack.split("\n");                                         

Error: No element indexed by 194

```

Answer (score 0):

Manually remove your node_modules folder and re-run `npm install` as it sounds like NPM didn't correctly install something.

Comment: that didn't do anything. still getting same error message

Comment: see the __temporary solution__ I just added

Answer (score 0):

You're using the latest version of Bluebird with an outdated version of node.

Comment: thank you for that input. Could you recommend a version of Bluebird to use with the version of node I am using?

Comment: @jeremy actually, can you come on chat? Or Twitter? We can try some other things out first. My Twitter is the same username.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that I was using another module `pretty-error` that was modifying the `console` object and therefore, `bluebird`s error handling was receiving a mutated `console` object that was not the shape that `bluebird` expected.